# PHP new lines in a text file

Tags: php, file

I am trying to add a new line to a text file in php

I current have the following line of code

```
file_put_contents($_SESSION["name"].'.txt', $_POST["item"]."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The goal of this line is to add a new file to a text file associated with a user. It works fine. However I need the text to display on separate lines

I want the text file to look like this

```
item1
item2
item3
etc..
```

right now it looks like `item1item2item3etc...`

how do I get the new line to show up in the text file?

Comment: If you're viewing this file in a browser, you're not seeing those newlines because HTML ignores them.

Comment: Yes, view the source of the page.  How do you want to display them?

Comment: I am not I am viewing them in a plain text file. I am running this on my local machine. I am not going to ever make it public so I am just saving some amounts of data to text files

Comment: I just did it and I have 5 lines of text. So it may be your text editor that is not reading it right.

Comment: Try to use PHP_EOL instead of \n. This is cross-platform.

Comment: How are you viewing the text. And when you say you have 5 lines does it actually display at five lines or do you just know that it is inserting line breaks?

Comment: Even if you add new line escape characters to the end of the line some operating systems also require carriage return (CR) so your best bet is to add `\n\r` instead of only `\n`.

Comment: After doing \r\n what extra parameter do I need to pass the file function? For example if I want to ignore line breaks I do file(f, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) that will strip all line breaks will it also take care of the extra \r?

Answer (score 1):

Try using \r\n instead otherwise the line breaks will not show in some systems / apps.

Comment: Yes, \r is an escape character so will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
file_put_contents("test.txt", "item".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents("test.txt", "item".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents("test.txt", "item".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Output test.txt:

```
item
item
item
```

PHP_EOL is cross platform and will work on Linux/Windows (does not matter where you run the code).